# Swift var addition does not work

Tags: ios, swift, var, addition

I have multiple var

Now I want my var totalScore to be = my other var added

here's my code

```
var section1score: Int = 0
var section2score: Int = 0
var section3score: Int = 0
var totalScore: Int = section1score + section2score + section3score
```

This code is not working... in var totalScore it's telling me that ViewController does not have a member named section1Score... and stops there

What am I doing wrong?

thanks !

Comment: you probably write wrong, it is not `section1Score` it is `section1score`

Comment: I ran this code in a playground and it doesn't give any errors. My guess is that you have some other error in your viewcontroller. Uncomment the lines and see if you can build.

Comment: Code is fine. Error is in other place

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write `totalScore` as a computed property so that it will always be the sum of the other 3 properties.

```
var totalScore: Int {
    get {
        return section1score + section2score + section3score
    }
}
```

Comment: You could omit `get` and just have `var totalScore: Int { return ... }` :)

Answer (score 1):

Is this code in a function? You cannot instance variables until init() has been completed. So if they are in a function this should work.

```
func test() {
    var section1score: Int = 0
    var section2score: Int = 0
    var section3score: Int = 0
    var totalScore: Int = section1score + section2score + section3score
}
```

Or if they need to be instance variables:

```
var section1score: Int = 0
var section2score: Int = 0
var section3score: Int = 0
var totalScore: Int = 0

init() {
    totalScore = section1score + section2score + section3score
}
```

Comment: it solved my error but keith's answer solved my sum problem thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var section1score: Int!
var section2score: Int!
var section3score: Int!
var totalScore: Int!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    section1score = 0
    section2score = 0
    section3score = 0

    totalScore = section1score + section2score + section3score
    println(totalScore)
 }
```